# Can't chown a timemachine file after migrating to a new Mac

Tags: macos, backup, terminal, permissions, time-machine

I followed the directions here:

http://www.macosxhints.com/comment.php?mode=display&format=threaded&order=ASC&pid=97623

Everything seemed to go well, but I still can't open my Time Machine backup. The console however revealed the problem:

```
8/10/09 6:14:15 PM [0x0-0x17f17f].com.apple.systempreferences[6210] chown: /Volumes/LaCie-1/.00254bccf5b2: Operation not permitted
```

I have tried to do get ownership in terminal and it says:

```
sudo chown "sanitizedUserName" .00254bccf5b2
Password:
chown: .00254bccf5b2: Operation not permitted
```

Any ideas how to get ownership?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, I had to plug the drive in USB. It would not work over the Network.